# Why is で used instead of に alongside ある？

Tags: particle-に, particle-で, に-and-で

I am wondering as to why で was used after 間 instead of に as I would expect because it is talking about popularity being present. What is the general definition for this usage of で？

> そのホテルは安くて清潔なので、旅行者たちの**間で**人気がある。

Comment: Not an answer, but 旅行者たちの間**で**人気がある sounds perfectly natural to me (I wouldn't say 旅行者たちの間**に**人気がある). 明鏡国語辞典 also gives examples: "あいだ【間】... ➎一定の集団などの内側。「若者の間**で**評判の歌手」「研究者の間**で**は常識だ」"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> そのホテルは安くて清潔なので、旅行者たちの間**で**人気がある。

The sentence sounds perfectly natural with で.

旅行者たちの間 is not the place 人気 exists. Actually, 人気 is present in そのホテル. Compare:

> - その歌手は人気がある。
>     *lit.* As for the singer, there's popularity. / The singer has popularity. → The singer is popular.
> - その選手は見込みがある。
>     *lit.* As for the player, there's prospect. / The player has prospect. → The player is promising.
> - 彼は人望がある。
>     *lit.* As for him, there's popularity/trust. / He has popularity/trust. →  He is popular/trusted.
> - 彼は才能がある。
>     *lit.* As for him, there's talent. / He has talent. → He is talented.

You can say:

> その歌手はフランス**で**人気がある。 The singer is popular in France.

but not その歌手はフランス**に**人気がある。Here, フランス is the place where the phenomenon その歌手は人気がある is occurring, not the place where 人気 exists / is present. So you use フランスで, not フランスに here.

Your example そのホテルは...旅行者たちの間**で**人気がある literally means "As for the hotel, there's popularity among tourists." → "The hotel is popular among tourists." 
You use で not に here, since 旅行者たちの間 is not the place where 人気 exists, but expresses among what kind of people, or in what group of people, the phenomenon そのホテルは人気がある is occurring.

<sub>In そのホテルは旅行者たち**に**人気がある, you use に. The に means "with", as in "The hotel is popular with tourists", indicating 対象/target.</sub>

Comment: I sense that a truncation is going on there. We probably don't say フランスで人々の間で人気がある, but likely say フランスで人々の間に人気がある. To be grammatically coherent, isn't it フランスで人気である?

Comment: さあ・・・。辞書（[若者の間で人気がある](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/若者の間で人気がある)）にも「で」で載ってますし、
 https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/3510343 でもネイティブ回答者が３人とも「若者**の間で**人気がある」「若者**に**人気がある」のほうが「若者**の間に**人気がある」「若者**で**人気がある」より自然だと回答してるので、「人々**の間で**人気がある」が自然だと思うのは、私だけではないようですが、まあ、人によるんでしょう。"(場所)で * の間に人気が[ある/あります/あってetc.]"はヒットしませんね。"(場所)で * の間で人気が[ある/あります/あってetc.]"は一件だけ。私なら「フランス**の**人々の間で人気がある。」「フランス**の**人々に人気がある。」「フランスで人気がある。」「フランスで人気だ。」って言うかな～と思います。

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering as to why で was used after 間 instead if に as I would expect because it is talking about popularity being present. What is the general definition for this usage of で？
>
> > そのホテルは安くて清潔なので、旅行者たちの間で人気がある

I think we native speakers are also confused about things like this because we are using them without knowing the grammar, but I feel the same way as you do. I feel it will sound better if it's
そのホテルは安くて清潔なので、旅行者たちに人気がある。
そのホテルは安くて清潔なので、旅行者たちの間に人気がある。
そのホテルは安くて清潔なので、旅行者たちの間で もてはやされている。
そのホテルは安くて清潔なので、旅行者たちの間で人気が出ている。

**[場所]で** is to say a location of a ***happening;*** どこそこ**で行う.** （花火大会｛はなびたいかい｝が広場｛ひろば｝**である** means a happening.）
**[場所]に** is to say a location of an ***existence;*** どこそこ**にある.**

Comment: It's basically like this among other usages:　**で**１ 動作・作用の行われる場所・場面を表す。https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/148951/meaning/m1u/　**に**２ 人・事物の存在や出現する場所を表す。https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166083/meaning/m1u/